# I want to send some data and image when client send request to server in c# using TCP/IP

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am new in socket programming. I did a simple message transfer from one process to another, but now I want to send image + data when the client sends a request to the server.
I am only able to send data or image, not both of them in a single request. How could I accomplish this?.

Comment: Bear in mind that TCP is a stream of bytes. That's what it gives you. If you want to deal in terms of *messages*, it's up to you to implement that on top of the stream of bytes - or to move to a higher level abstraction that gives you messaging.

Comment: An image is nothing but data. Why not box both image & data in a custom object, and then unbox it at the other end?

Comment: thanks @AdamCalvetBohl

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned in comments, in context of TCP/IP all sending \ receiving process based on streaming the array of bytes. 
You can use the following algorithm (it is not the copy-paste solution) :

1. Create some custom type that contains data : may be string and **I strongly recommend to store only path string** to origin image.

`class StreamData {string dataPath {get;set;} string imagePath {get;set;} }`

1. Add another abstraction level class that convert data (image, music) to byte array and get the path of data to convert.`class StreamConverter{ //some awesome method(string path)}`.

And just send this data to client. Also don't forget about how client will deserialize/encode this data.

Comment: Thanks sir but image path will be given if both process are on same machine but my both  process are run on different machines.I want to transfer image file